# How can I map array items to new object with custom properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, for-loop

This is my array:

```
const arr = ['first string', 'second string'];
```

How can I map this, so I get:

```
const obj = {'first string': 'found', 'second string', 'found'};
```

I have tried this:

`const obj = arr.forEach(item => {item: 'found'})` but it is not working.

Comment: Object can not have 2 keys with name name..

Comment: I'm not sure if you know this, but an object cannot have two keys of the same value

Comment: This is different key, this is only mockup. Will edit now.

Comment: @Ivan I'm not sure how map would solve the problem. `Reduce` I could see, but map?

Comment: @TKoL ah, yeah, not attentive, thinking that array required

Comment: @Ivan there's an answer below that DOES utilize map, but that's a pretty obscure way of doing things imo. I've never seen that before. I guess it's kinda clever though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` instead of `forEach()`

**BUT, you cannot assign duplicate keys to an object.**

```js
const arr = ['some string', 'some string', 'another string', 'totally different'];


var obj = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur] = 'found'
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const arr = ['first string', 'second string'];
const res = Object.assign({}, ...arr.map((s) => ({[s]: 'found'})));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:-

```
const obj = {};
arr.forEach(item => {
    obj[item] = 'found';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure about what you want, but this maybe your solution:

```js
const arr = ['some string1', 'some string2'];
const ans = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(item => [item, 'found']));
console.log(ans);
```